# How to solve error "Assigning single elements to varargs in named form is forbidden"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

We use Spring Boot with Kotlin. We recently upgraded Kotlin code from 1.1.X version to 1.4.X. After this upgrade we are getting many vararg related compilation issues.

Code:

```
interface OutageClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET), value = "/mass-outages")
    fun getMassOutages( @RequestParam("state") state: String): MassOutage
```

Compilation issue I am getting is:

> Assigning single elements to varargs in named form is forbidden

We are getting this issue around `value = "/mass-outages"` part of code.

Comment: Wrap it in `[]`.

Comment: ohh , so straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning single elements to varargs in named form have been [deprecated](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20171) since kotlin 1.3.

To solve this you can use [array literal syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#arrays-as-annotation-parameters), which is allowed for annotations

```
value = ["/mass-outages"]
```